# appending 2 2D arrays without arraycopy

Tags: java, arrays, append

i need to append 2 2D arrays without using arraycopy and by order, first arr1 then arr2, like so:

```
int[][] arr1 = {{1,2},{7,9,10}};
int[][] arr2 = {{3,5,7,9},{16,10,11}}; 
int[][] arr3 = append(arr1,arr2);
result should be:
1 2 
7 9 10 
3 5 7 9 
16 10 11
```

i've tried:

```
    public static int[][] append(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2) {
    int [][] arr3 = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length][];
    for (int i=0; i<arr1.length; i=i+1) {
        for (int j=0; j<arr1[i].length; j=j+1) {
            arr3[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int x=arr1.length; x<arr3.length-2; x=x+1) {
        int a=0;
        for (int y=0; y<arr2[a].length; y=y+1) {
            arr3[x][y] = arr2[a][y];
            a=a+1;
        }
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

But I'm getting a null pointer exception at line 
'arr3[i][j] = arr1[i][j];'
What can I do?
thanks for the help!!

Comment: And what is not working like you expect with your code?  You don't actually ask a question currently.  Please tell us what you are confused about.

Comment: I forgot to mention the exception I'm getting, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You are not defining the length of each `arr3[i]`
2. You are resetting the `a` variable each time you go through the second for loop. Declaring it needs to go outside the first loop and incrementing it needs to go outside the second loop (at the end of the first loop).

Change your code to something like this:

```
public static int[][] append(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2) {
  int [][] arr3 = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length][];
  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i = i+1) {
    arr3[i] = new int[arr1[i].length];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j = j+1) {
      arr3[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
    }
  }

  int a = 0;
  for (int x = arr1.length; x < arr3.length; x = x+1) {
    arr3[x] = new int[arr2[a].length];
    for (int y = 0; y < arr2[a].length; y = y+1) {
      arr3[x][y] = arr2[a][y];
    }
    a = a+1;
  }
  return arr3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You could use streams*
*(although they are a few ms slower)*

```
int[] array = IntStream.concat(
      IntStream.concat(IntStream.of( arr1[0] ), IntStream.of( arr1[1] )),
      IntStream.concat(IntStream.of( arr2[0] ), IntStream.of( arr2[1] )) )
          .flatMap(IntStream::of).toArray();
```

to use `arr1` and `arr2` directly:

```
Stream.of( arr1, arr2 ).flatMap(Stream::of).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
```

gets: `[1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 3, 5, 7, 9, 16, 10, 11]`